# Hausdorff dimension and von Neumann dimension

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, von-neumann-algebras, big-picture, fractals, hausdorff-dimension

There are two subjects in which non-integral dimensions appear:

- [fractal geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal):  consider the well-known [Hausdorff dimension of fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension).
- [von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra): consider a type ${\rm II_1}$ factor $M$ and a [$M$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Modules_over_a_factor) $H$, then von Neumann defined a notion of $M$-dimension $\dim_M(H) \in [0, \infty]$. Moreover, for any $\alpha \in [0, \infty]$ there is a $M$-module $H_{\alpha}$ with $\dim_M(H_{\alpha}) = \alpha$ (and two $M$-modules of same $M$-dimension are isomorphic).

**Question**: Is there a link between Hausdorff dimension and von Neumann dimension ?

More precisely, from a given fractal $\mathcal{F}$ of Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$, can we make a type ${\rm II_1}$ factor $M$ and a $M$-module $H$ such that $\dim_M(H) = \alpha$ ?
Or conversely, from a given type ${\rm II_1}$ factor $M$ and $M$-module $H$ with $\dim_M(H) = \alpha$, can we naturally make a fractal of Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$? Should we *intuitively* think about a connected or a totally disconnected fractal (like a Cantor set)? If $\alpha \le 2$, is there a natural way to draw it?

*Remark*: such a link already exists between Hausdorff dimension of fractals and dimension spectrum of Connes' spectral triples (see "Fractals in Noncommutative Geometry" by Guido-Isola [arXiv:math/0102209](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0102209), [MR1867554](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1867554), inspired by Chapter 4, Section 3 of [Connes' book](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf)).

*Remark*: there also exist notions of (non-integral) quantum dimension, statistical dimension, Perron-Frobenius dimension (of an object in a (unitary) fusion category), or subfactor index, but (most of the time) they can be formulated in term of a von Neumann dimension.

Comment: Interesting question... nothing jumps to mind.

Comment: Possibly relevant is Yuri I. Manin's 2006 Bull. AMS paper [*The notion of dimension in geometry and algebra*](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2006-43-02/S0273-0979-06-01081-0/).

Comment: Yeah, this is a good question.